# Full calendar event timezone issue on local and publish

Tags: c#, jquery, timezone, fullcalendar, momentjs

When fullcalendar is implemented in local machine it works properly.But when i triying to host in a server located at uk the time events not assigned properly.Timezone issue is the reason.NB:Changing timezone option to local to utc or vice versa doesn't helps.

**Backend**  : `c# MVC`

**Plugins used version:**

```
FullCalendar v3.6.1

Moment.js :version : 2.19.2
```

**Requirement:**

event should displayed correctly to an user in India and user with a different timezone

```
var calendar = $('#calendarForGDiary');
calendar.fullCalendar(fullCalendarOptions());  
function fullCalendarOptions() {

            var options = {
                lazyFetching: false,
                editable: true, // Don't allow editing of events
                handleWindowResize: true,
                weekends: true, // Hide weekends
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek', // Only show week view
                header: true, // Hide buttons/titles
                minTime: '00:00:00', // Start time for the calendar
                maxTime: '24:00:00', // End time for the calendar
                overlap: false,
                timezone: 'local',              
                eventConstraint: {
                    start: '0:00',
                    end: '24:00'
                },
                droppable: true,
                drop: function (date) {
                },
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:00',
                axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
                slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm",
                eventOverlap: false,
                allDaySlot: false,
                slotDuration: '00:05',
                slotLabelInterval: '01:00',
                header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'today prev,next, Date'
                },
                firstDay: 1,
                businessHours: {
                    // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
                    dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],

                    start: '00:00', // a start time
                    end: '7:30', // an end time
                },
                displayEventTime: true,
                views: {
                    agenda: {
                        timeFormat: 'HH:mm', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
                        columnFormat: 'ddd DD/MM/YY',
                    }
                },
                dragRevertDuration: 0,
                events:{
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetIssueLogsByDate")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function ()
                    {
                        $.fullCalendar.moment().stripZone()
                    },
                    error: function () { ShowErrorModal("Unable To Load Log Details") }
                },
                scrollTime: "00:00:00",
                eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
                    ChangeIssueLogDate(event);
                },
                eventReceive: function (event) {
                    addNewEvent(event);
                },
                loading: function (bool) {
                    $('#imgLoadingForGemini').modal('show');
                },
                eventAfterAllRender: function (view)
                {                   
                    modifyCalendarForTimeOverflow();
                    $('.eventButtons').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#imgLoadingForGemini').modal('hide');
                },

                eventClick: function (event, jsEvent) {
                    ShowEventDetailsModal(event, jsEvent);
                },
                eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
                    UpdateLogTimeByLogID(delta._data, event.id);
                },
                eventRender: function (event, element, view)
                {                    
                   // moment(event._d.start, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                    //$.fullCalendar.moment(event.d).stripZone()
                    console.log(event)

                },
                moment: { stripZone:true },

            }
            return options
        }
```

Controller code
 public async Task GetIssueLogsByDate(DateTime start)
        { 
            try
            {
                start = DateTime.Parse(start.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
                //DateTime monday = Date.start.Date;
                Log activeDates = new Log();
                activeDates.Date = start.Date;
                activeLogs = await GDiaryBLL.GetUserLogsByUserID(activeDates);

[this how same event in local displayed in when i published in uk server date difference check the dates as well as event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQjp5.png)

[same event in local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R90cQ.png)

Comment: Could you give details about exactly what you're seeing vs what you expect to see, and how you've diagnosed the problem so far? (It's not clear what C# has to do with this at the moment - it may well be involved, but you haven't shown us any of the C# code, so it's hard to tell.) The `moment: {stripZone: true}` part sounds like it may be relevant, but without knowing what you're seeing vs what you expect to see, that's hard to tell too.

Comment: check the sreenshot.As you said it has nothing do with c#code

Comment: I need both the views be same as inn the screenshot local server

Comment: If the calendar entry isn't showing up *at all* it's not clear that this is a time zone issue.

Comment: Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone - setting the timezone option in fullCalendar merely causes a hint to be given to the server about the timezone. The server then has to return events with the correct timezone offset. Are you doing that? We can't see your event data or C# code so we don't know.

Comment: And `$.fullCalendar.moment().stripZone()` does nothing useful - you create an empty moment and then strip its zone, but then discard it. It achieves nothing and is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Anyway, I wonder if your events are not showing because your `events` callback function never passes the events to fullCalendar. You've overriden the "success" callback option which I suspect means that the default functionality of returning the events to the calendar won't happen. Try removing that from your code (as I said above, nothing useful happens in there anyway).

Comment: can u tell me how to set dateformat in fullcalendar and also to pass date in mm-dd-yyyy from view to cntroller in option parameter:events

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed by Changing Time Zone:"UTC"
Changing the format of data

Comment: option{timezone:"UTC"}